# How to pass projects in order in FAKE

Tags: f#-fake

I need to build vb6 projects in order. How should I pass them to Vb6Make?

```
let projs = [
    "a.vbp"
    "b.vbp"
    "c.vbp"
    ]

Target "VB6" (fun _ ->
    !! projs // <- ?
     |> Vb6Make
)
```

Answer (score 0):

!! and ++ can be used for single files files as well. And FullName is important for directories.

```
let vb6dir = FullName "./bin"
let tempdir = FullName "./temp"

let projs = 
    !! "src\a\a.vbp"
    ++ "src\b\b.vbp"
    ++ "src\c\c.vbp"

Target "BuildVb6" (fun _ ->
     projs
     |> Fake.Vb6Helper.Vb6Make(fun c ->
        { c with
            Logdir = tempdir
            Outdir = vb6dir })
)
```